# Family sharing payment information verification bug

Tags: icloud, family-sharing

I have family sharing enabled and when a family member tries to purchase something (in this case purchasing more iCloud storage) they are asked to ask an organizer to verify by entering the credit card security code.

When the security code is entered and "Done" is pressed nothing happens. (Except I get a notification from my bank that ITUNES.COM has charged me 1$, every time "Done" is pressed.) Nothing here means literally nothing, the shade of the button changes on press but that's it, no dialog, no text, nothing.

This happens regardless of which device is used. I've tried this on two iPhones, iPad and a Macbook.

The current status is that no one in my family can purchase anything and I've payed 12$ in verification fees(?) trying to figure this out. It seems a bit crazy. Any thoughts?

Comment: I've noticed that Apple does not immediately charge the full value of purchases. I've had iTunes songs, movies ordered on my AppleTV, software downloaded from the App Store, etc, all show up in a few days to a _few weeks_ later. So long as the song appears in my iTunes Library / the movie starts playing / the app downloads, I know I'm OK. The $1 charges are to verify the account exists. Did the increased iCloud storage appear relatively quickly?

Comment: No, the items I attempt to purchase aren't purchased at all. Literally _nothing_ happens.